# Nginx not properly re-directing when user types https://

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate

I have a couple re-directs in place to ensure all domains and variations are pointing to the current primary location:

```
#redirects www
server {
    server_name www.blah.net;
    return 301 https://blah.org$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name www.blah.co;
    return 301 https://blah.org$request_uri;
}

#redirects co and net to org
server {
    server_name blah.co;
    return 301 https://blah.org$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name blah.net;
    return 301 https://blah.org$request_uri;
}

#redirects all traffic to https
server {
    listen *:80 default_server;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

#main server
server {
    listen *:443 ssl;
    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.blah.org/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.blah.org/privkey.pem;

    root /home/blah/www;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name blah.org blah.co blah.net;
}
```

Issue is that our top google search results has a link that points to `https://blah.co` and when you click it, it gives a cert error. I understand what the problem is, I just have no idea how to fix the redirects so that when someone clicks a link that includes `https` or types out `https://blah.co` it resolves to `https://blah.org`.

Comment: Get valid certificate for `blah.co`

Comment: @AlexeyTen The point is to avoid that - and redirect all traffic at blah.org which is the only site that has a valid cert.

Comment: The point of https is to make impossible to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will work.  The first block should catch any traffic that is not https://blah.org, and redirect it.  And the second server block only handles the blah.org domain.

```
# redirects all non-.org traffic to https
server {
    listen *:80 default_server;
    listen *:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.blah.org/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.blah.org/privkey.pem;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        return 301 https://blah.org$request_uri;
    }
}

#main server
server {
    listen *:443 ssl;
    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.blah.org/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.blah.org/privkey.pem;

    root /home/blah/www;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name blah.org;
}
```

Comment: This still need valid certs

Comment: @AlexeyTen I am not arguing against you, however I have the reverse of this working in a production environment.    We 301 redirect all `non-https` `non-www` traffic to https://www.domain.com, and we only have a wildcard ssl certificate.  Even `http://ip-address` redirects properly.